# Focus auto jump between several <p:inputNumber>

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a web with several <p:inputNumber> (Primefaces)
[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c7oh.png) with several <p:inputNumber> (Primefaces)

Example of <p:inputNumber>

```
<p:inputNumber id="sbAddXm" value="#{point.xm}"
           styleClass="coordinate-field"
           maxlength="2"
           inputStyle="margin: 0 0 7px 0; font-size: 16px;"
           autocomplete="off"
           onkeyup="clearError(this)"
           decimalPlaces="0" thousandSeparator=""
           validator="fractionNumberValidator">
<p:keyFilter mask="pint" preventPaste="false" />
<f:attribute name="minimum" value="0"/>
<f:attribute name="maximum" value="59"/>
<f:attribute name="summary" value="Ошибка: "/>
<f:attribute name="detail" value="«Долгота - минуты» должно быть число от 0 до 59"/>
<p:ajax event="focus" oncomplete="select(this)"/>
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{editEntityView.doReRender}"/>
<f:ajax event="keyup" render="addOrEditSubsoilBorderModal:SBmessage
                                addOrEditSubsoilBorderModal:addSubsoilBorderSaveBtn
                                addOrEditSubsoilBorderModal:editSubsoilBorderSaveBtn"/>
```

</p:inputNumber>

The problem appear when I try to  fill several inputs (switch between inputs by press tab or by mouse click on field).

Problem is: focus begin to jump between input fields automatically in cycle.
If I pause script in Chrome debuger by F8, I see that looping somewhere in [jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJjI9.png), but I didn't use jQuery in this form.

Comment: Tried with the latest version of PrimeFaces? I noticed you are using 7. Also, please add a [mcve]. You seem to be using some kind of UI repeater which could be relevant here.

Comment: Also don't use `<p:ajax event="focus" oncomplete="select(this)"/>` for focus just on your `inputNumber` put `onfocus="select(this)"`since it seems you just want to use client Side Javascript and not a server side AJAX call.

Comment: it seems to have to do with the change event, and what it does in the doReRender method when the listener calls it. Have you tried dropping events to narrow down to know the problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments.  I put onfocus="select(this)" without ajax, and now it works. @Melloware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is the solution of the problem:

> Also don't use <p:ajax event="focus" oncomplete="select(this)"/> for focus just on your inputNumber put onfocus="select(this)"since it seems you just want to use client Side Javascript and not a server side AJAX call. – Melloware

Thank you!

Comment: No problem glad i was able to help!